# C#6's Improved overload resolution - clarification?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Among all the new features in C#6, the most mysterious feature (to me) is the *"improved overload resolution"*.

Maybe it's because I [*couldn't find*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx) related info/examples/explanation about it.

> The only two remaining features not discussed are support for defining
>   a custom Add extension method to help with collection initializers,
>   **and** some minor but improved overload resolution

Looking at the [*roslyn wiki*](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)

> There are a number of small improvements to overload resolution, which
>   will likely result in more things just working the way you’d expect
>   them to. The improvements all relate to “betterness” – the way the
>   compiler decides which of two overloads is better for a given
>   argument.

And so I ask:

**Question**:

How exactly do the *Improved overload resolution* comes into play in C#6? And *how* it is different from C#5 *(Example? Documentation?)*

Comment: http://bc-programming.com/blogs/2015/06/c-6-features-improved-overload-resolution/

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you Hans. However the link states _"In Visual Studio 2015, this code fails to compile_". But it does compile and run

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I suspect it should have said "In Visual Studio 2013, this code fails to compile" - VS 2015 is the version that uses C# 6, after all. See also: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/specs/CSharp%206/Better%20Betterness.md

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe what is meant here is the "better betterness" rules which are [documented in the Roslyn github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/specs/CSharp%206/Better%20Betterness.md).

Sample code:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Foo(Action action) {}
    static void Foo(Func<int> func) {}
    static int Bar() { return 1; }

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(Bar);        
    }
}
```

Using the C# 5 compiler (e.g. in `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`) this gives two errors:

> Test.cs(11,9): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>        'Test.Foo(System.Action)' and 'Test.Foo(System.Func)'
>   Test.cs(11,13): error CS0407: 'int Test.Bar()' has the wrong return type

Using the C# 6 compiler, it compiles fine.

Likewise using exact matching for lambda expressions, this generates an ambiguous overload error with the C# 5 compiler, but not for C# 6:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Foo(Func<Func<long>> func) {}
    static void Foo(Func<Func<int>> func) {}

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(() => () => 7);
    }
}
```