# How were the rules for overload resolution changed in C# 6.0 and since?

Tags: c#, overloading, language-lawyer, specifications, c#-6.0

On the [C# 6.0 features page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6), it is said that overload resolution was improved by implementing a "better betterness".

For C# 5.0, the rules for determining candidate methods and then the best method were given in the specification. However, no specification exists for C# 6.0, and all posts from the Roslyn team merely speak along the lines of "it is now better" or, in the page I linked, "details aren't worth expanding here".

Is there a public page (perhaps some language design notes, though I couldn't find any) where the details are available? Failing that, are there test cases in the Roslyn codebase that document the changes?

I found [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114291/c6s-improved-overload-resolution-clarifictaion) asking the same thing from January, but there is no answer.

Comment: If you find an unanswered question that you also have, don't repost the question. Add a bounty or edit it to bump it.