# C#6 Overload Resolution Func<T1> & Func<T2>

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

I know from [this question\answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35114291/442351) that the improvements in the overload resolution is that it includes the return type of a lambda in the resolution of the overload.

The example given on the [site linked in the answer](http://bc-programming.com/blogs/2015/06/c-6-features-improved-overload-resolution/) gives this:

```
class Program
{
    private static void TakesItem(Action item)
    {

    }
    private static int TakesItem(Func<int> item)
    {
        return item();
    }
    public static int somefunction()
    {
        return 50;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int resultitem = TakesItem(somefunction);
        Console.WriteLine(resultitem);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This code will compile in version 6 and not in version 5.

I've tried changing it functions returning different types:

```
private void Foo(Func<int> func)
{
}

private void Foo(Func<string> func)
{

}

private int Bar()
{
    return 1;
}

[Test]
public void Example()
{
    Foo(Bar);
}
```

This doesn't compile in C# 6 though, despite the `Func` returning different values.

Comment: You could explicitly cast Bar() to Func<int>
Foo((Func<int>)Bar);

Comment: Aye, but that worked in C# 5 as well, so it'l not to do with the new resolution enhancements.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think, specifically, that any changes relate to the *return type*. That's not mentioned in the question you link to and, so far as I'm aware, return types are not considered to be part of the signature in C# (1.0-7.0)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Here's a quote from the article: "_C# 6 however how includes return type as part of function overload resolution, which allows it to unambiguously find the TakesItem(Func) matches the usage._".  It certainally does differentiate between the `Action` and the `Func`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I assumed (incorrectly) that this would extend to analysing the type of the return type rather than just its existance.

Comment: I'd normally go and look to the spec but unfortunately, the last official published spec is for C# 5. There's a github spec that claims to be a draft and that will be out-dated when the C# 6 is published, *before end of 2016 at the latest*... I won't bother linking to it, but you may be able to search through it.

Comment: Cheers @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I've had a look about for something but there's precious little on this.  i suspect the only option is to look at the source (which can wait until later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the relevant part of [the specification changes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/specs/CSharp%206/Better%20Betterness.md) is here:

> 7.5.3.5 Better conversion target
>
> Given two different types T1 and T2, T1 is a better conversion target than T2 if
> …
> •T1 is either a delegate type D1 or an expression tree type Expression<D1>, T2 is either a delegate type D2 or an expression tree type Expression<D2>, D1 has a return type S1 and one of the following holds:
> ◦D2 is void returning
> ◦D2 has a return type S2, and S1 is a better conversion target than S2
> …

Note that `void`-returning delegate types are special-cased. So in the new rules, `Func<int>` is a "better conversion target" than `Action`, because `Action` is `void`-returning.

In your second example, where there is still ambiguity, that is because the conversion doesn't meet any of the requirements stated. Both delegate types are *not* `void`-returning, and neither delegate type's return type is "better" than the other. That is, `int` is not "better than" `string`.

Note that `int` *is* "better than" `object`. So if you change the `Func<string>` to `Func<object>`, the compiler is able to choose and you no longer get the error.