# call is ambiguous .WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<IWin32Window>) and (Func<IntPtr>)

Tags: c#, msbuild

Please help me to understand why it happens

> call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'PublicClientApplicationBuilder.WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<IWin32Window>)' and 'PublicClientApplicationBuilder.WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<IntPtr>)'

I'm using the `PublicClientApplicationBuilder.WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<IntPtr>)` method from the `microsoft.identity.client`  assembly.

there are three methods actually

```
WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<object> parentActivityOrWindowFunc);
WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<IWin32Window> windowFunc);
WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<IntPtr> windowFunc);
```

my source code looks like

```cs
class Program
{
    static IntPtr GetHandle()
    {
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WithParentActivityOrWindow(GetHandle);
    }
    static void WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<object> parentActivityOrWindowFunc) { }
    static void WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<IWin32Window> windowFunc) { }
    static void WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<IntPtr> windowFunc) { }
}
```

The problem is that `WithParentActivityOrWindow(GetHandle);` compiles on the latest VS2019 (that uses msbuild 16.9)

but fails on VS2017 (on the same computer) that uses msbuild 15.9.21

to make it works in VS2017 I have to adjust the `WithParentActivityOrWindow` call like below

```
WithParentActivityOrWindow(() => GetHandle());
```

that looks pretty the same for me.

Please help me to understand what is the difference ?

#### UPD

[here is the repo](https://github.com/oleksabor/effective-spoon)

#### UPD2

it looks like `() => GetHandle()` is actually Func declaration. And compiler can choose proper method since return type is a part of generic Func type of the parameter.

However `GetHandle` is just a method. And C# (like C) ignores return type of the method when choosing which overloaded method to use (C# has ignored until 7.3 version).

It works for C# below 7.3 if `GetHandle` (and `WithParentActivityOrWindow` parameter) has overloaded variants with additional parameter like `Func<TIn, TOut>`

```cs
static void WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<bool, IWin32Window> windowFunc) { }
static void WithParentActivityOrWindow(Func<int, IntPtr> windowFunc) { }

static IntPtr GetHandle(int) {}

WithParentActivityOrWindow(GetHandle);
```

Comment: Which version of .NET are you targetting?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel thank you for the question the target is .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: This works in the later version because of [improvements to overload resolution so it now looks at the return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114291/c6s-improved-overload-resolution-clarification). This was introduced by C# 6, so it should work in VS2017 if you change the project so that it is targeting C# 6 or later.

Comment: .NET 4.8 on VS2017 does target C# 7 by default, so it _should_ work, so something else must be going on.

Comment: @MatthewWatson it works in VS2017 with `<LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>` (or _latest minor_) only, thanks a lot. Nor `6` nor `7.2` are not working O_o

Comment: If 7.3 fixes it then perhaps this is why: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#improved-overload-candidates